# set CancellationPending to false after CancelAsync() request backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Class A contains two events `buttonStart_Click`, `buttonCancel_Click`. When Start button is Click `BackgroundWorker` start process.

Now When Cancel button clicked one MessageBox is pop up and if user click on Yes button `BackgroundWorker` stop processing and if user click on No button BackgroundWorker resume processing.

Now the problem is after `bgw.CancelAsync()`  `CancellationPending` become true now i want to make `CancellationPending` to false after user click on no in messagebox.

can anyone have idea how can i do it or any other solution?

```
public partial class A : Form
{
  private BackgroundWorker bgw;

  private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       // Make cancel request
       if (bgw != null)
       {
           bgw.CancelAsync();
       }
  }

  private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    B objB=new B();
    bgw = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };
    bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(objB.Work);            
  }
}

class B
{
      private bool WantToCancle()
      {
           DialogResult Result= MessageBox.Show("Are you want to cancel?", "Cancel ?",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

           return Result == DialogResult.Yes ? true : false;
      }
      public void Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
           While(condition...)
           {  
              ......
              if(((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancellationPending)
              {
                  if(WantToCancle()){return;}
              }  
          }  
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why not just put the `WantToCancle()` _[sic]_ method call in the `Click` event handler, _before_ you call `CancelAsync()`? Fact is, you have to do it that way...you can't "uncancel" a cancelled worker. But why did that not occur to you? What is keeping you from doing it that way?

Comment: In your suggestion message box will open but still background is in process the other code but i want to stop background worker's process that's why it is there  @PeterDuniho

Comment: I disagree with your design goal. If the prompt is there to ask the user if they really want to cancel the operation, then why interrupt the operation at all? Why not let it proceed, until you know _for sure_ that the user wants it canceled? But regardless, you can't cancel the worker and then uncancel it. If you want it to pause while you wait for user input, you need to add your own mechanism for that (such as a semaphore or wait handle).

Comment: Let's take a example if the application is like copy and paste system then i have to ask to user about cancel process @PeterDuniho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All i need to do is invoke.

```
  private bool WantToCancle()
  {
        DialogResult Result = DialogResult.Yes;

        Application.OpenForms["form name"].Invoke((Func<DialogResult>)(() =>
        Result =MessageBox.Show("Are you want to cancel?", "Cancel ?",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        return Result == DialogResult.Yes ? true : false;
   }
```